# Access a value in an array in smarty

Tags: arrays, smarty

[image: image of smarty debug template]

My main problem is that i have a variable called "playlist_list" that contains an array in JSON format, for each item, that contains inside a value that i want to get.

It's something like this:

```
playlist_list => "{"jrAudio":{"30":0,"32":1,"37":2,"38":3}}"
```

and in this case i would like to get as a result the number "30".

Can someone help me find how to do it? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my own problem, so i hope it helps anyone:

```
{$playlist = json_decode($item.playlist_list,true)}
                        {foreach $playlist as $id => $position}
                            {foreach $position as $id1 => $position1}
                                {if $position1==0}
                                    {jrCore_module_function function="jrImage_display" module="jrAudio" type="audio_image" item_id=$id1 size="medium" crop="width" class="dker" alt="artist photo"}
                                {/if}
                            {/foreach}
                        {/foreach}
```